# => Angularjs. Am I understanding this correctly for values passed in?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working through a Udemy course on RxJs 6 and need to ask this as it was not crystal clear to me.

Note: This is a type ahead tutorial I am currently in at the moment. So on the keyup event this method is firing off.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const searchLessons$ = fromEvent<any>(this.input.nativeElement, 'keyup')
    .pipe(
      map(event => event.target.value),
      debounceTime(400),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      // switchMap cancels prior calls.
      switchMap(search => this.loadLessons(search))
    );

  const initialLessons$ = this.loadLessons();

  this.lessons$ = concat(initialLessons$, searchLessons$);
}
```

Does the code mean,

1. for all events that fire the code will collect responses from completed calls to the *loadLessons*
2. the value of the event is referenced as *search*
3. then the => will trigger a call to the *loadLessons(search)*
4. Continue of 3: If the value of the event were lets just say an array of values, would that mean that for the => call, a separate call to the *loadLessons(search)* would be made passing for each individual array value
5. Continue of 3: or would it just pass in the entire array?

Answer (score 2):

Here is line per line explanation:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const searchLessons$ = fromEvent<any>(this.input.nativeElement, 'keyup') // whenever keyup is triggered on this.input
    .pipe(
      map(event => event.target.value), // we extract input value from event target
      debounceTime(400), // we wait for last event in 400ms span
      distinctUntilChanged(), // we check that the input value did change
      switchMap(search => this.loadLessons(search)) // and with that input value changed we call this.LoadLessons and then wait for its return
    );

  const initialLessons$ = this.loadLessons(); // this will call initial loadLeason

  this.lessons$ = concat(initialLessons$, searchLessons$); // this will connect return of initial call and changes triggered by key up this is not secure for race conditions
}
```

Ad1. all key up events on input

Ad2. the value of **input** is referenced as search

Ad3. yes it would just push array as argument

Comment: Hey, @xesenix for Ad3. You mean the entire array as one call and not the individual values within the array as multiple calls?

Comment: Yes one time call, let say your `event.target.value` is and array it will be go all through as that array into `search` and it passed all steps till `switchMap` it will be put as one time call array into loadLesson first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the loadLessons func, i can only assume. i will also assume you are using the concat Rxjs method.

So basically what the code does, get the "initial load of lessons" , and subscribe to it on the concatMethod, after that call completes, it goes to subscribe to the second observable searchLessons.

The searchLessons will be called again every input search, and add the new values to the lessons subscription, on the search observable .

If the params given to the loadSeassion is an array, it will depend how that method (loadSessions) works. not with rxjs although it can be done in this case i cant really tell you :)